# Convergence diagnostic of Markov chain that converge to uniform

Tags: references, markov-process, convergence, heuristic

Let $\Omega$ be a finite state space, $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a discrete-time Markov chain that converges to the uniform distribution, and $P$ be its transition matrix. I'm looking for different methods that estimates the distance in *total variance* to uniform at the $k$-step, that is
$$\|P^k\cdot\pi-\left(\frac{1}{|\Omega|},\ldots,\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\right)\|_{TV}$$

for an initial distribution $\pi$. What heuristics are available that are broadly accepted?

So far, I tried an empirical approach that works as follows: Let $n:=|\Omega|$ and assume that after $k$-th steps of the Markov chain, you have observed $x_1,\ldots,x_m\in\Omega$, where you have seen sample $x_i$ exactly $s_i$ times (as a consequence $s_1+\ldots+s_m=k$). Then the distance to the uniform distribution in the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm is precisely

$$\sum_{i=1}^m\left|\frac{s_i}{k}-\frac{1}{n}\right|+\frac{n-m}{n}.$$

In theory, this approach works. However, for giant samples spaces $\Omega$ (even if we possess a good approximation of $|\Omega|$), the evaluation of the sum is expensive in space and time since $m$ became huge during the computation.

Comment: can you explain the norm $||\cdot||_{TV}$?

Comment: Look at the eigenvalues of $P$.

Comment: Are you looking for a theoretical understanding of convergence, or more for convergence in practice?

Comment: @Bey: Total Variation Distance.

Comment: @Greenparker: I'm looking for a convergence measurement in practice.

Comment: @whuber: I'm aware that the second largest eigenvalue of $P$ measures convergence. However, I don't have $P$ explicitely. Typically, $\Omega$ is humongous and there is now way to get a spectral decomposition of $P$.

Comment: @TobiasWindisch Since you know the invariant distribution, you can produce samples until their empirical distribution is uniform, in the sense of total variation.

Comment: @Greenparker: Yes, this is possible and I have tried this already. In this approach, you need to store all the samples that you get and you have to remember how often you have seen any sample. As it turns out, you need quite a lot of samples (a huge proportion of $\Omega$) and to compute the distance in total variance at any step is expensive, in both space and time.

Answer (score 1):

You're interested in what's more generally called  *mixing time* of a Markov chain which asks what the minimum $k$ is such that the total variation distance between your chain $P^k\pi$ and its stationary distribution is bounded by $\epsilon$. Even in finite state space, questions about mixing time can be highly nontrivial, and there exist many techniques for estimating them, for example as whuber mentions about looking at eigenvalues (particularly ratios of the largest$\neq 1$ over the smallest eigenvalues) of your chain. Perhaps your best bet is to take a look at one of the bibles on this topic: [*Markov Chains and Mixing Times* by Levin, Peres and Wilmer](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf), specifically chapter 4 and 12.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm familiar with the theory of spectral gaps, mixing times, second largest eigenvalues, and the book of Levin et al. I'm looking more for a heuristic that to estimate the mixing time in practice. In my application, there is now way to get $P$ explicitely.

Comment: @TobiasWindisch: it would really help if you specify what your $P$ is even if it's not possible to get explicitly. For example there are techniques for bounding TV by using a coupled markov chain which might be possible to find for your $P$. Otherwise the best you can say is something like $\|P^kx-\pi\|<Cr^k$ for some constants $C$ and $r\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Well, $P$ is the simple random walk on a $d$-regular graph $G$, that's all I can provide a priori. Unfortunately, $G$ can be any $d$-regular graph. Thats the reason why I hoped for a heuristic.

Comment: @TobiasWindisch: that's a huge amount of information because you can use explicit conductance bounds and cheeger inequalities: http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/erdos.pdf

Comment: Please add that graph information to the body of your question.

Comment: The conductance is not constrained to the simple walk and the cheeger constant is NP-hard to compute in general. Could you please explain how this additional information makes the problem easier? As I said in my previous comment, $G$ could be any graph.

Comment: @TobiasWindisch: yes calculating conductance exactly is NP hard but there are decent approximation algorithms, such as the one here: http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-readings/arora04expansion.pdf

Look I hear your frustration but this stuff is not easy, and I doubt you'll find a cookie-cutter way of making these estimations for arbitrary graphs.